# TypeScript - how to get client's machine name in IE and Chrome

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

**This is not a duplicate question**. I am asking for **TypeScript** not JavaScript in ASP.NET or JavaScript standalone or C#.

How can we get client machine name in TypeScript?

I tried below and it works good in IE. I want same in Chrome.

```
// after import statements and before @Component statement
declare var ActiveXObject: (type: string) => void; 

// somewhere in your typescript code. This works for IE
const network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');            
console.log(network.computerName);
console.log(network.userName);
console.log(network.userDomain);
```

**UPDATE**

Above works but not ideal solution. In IE, it is showing a popup asking to run ActiveX which my users does not want.

**UPDATE Aug 06 2018**

For now we decided not to use ClientPAddress or ClientMachineName in our logs. We will look later but at one point of time we certainly will do.

Comment: now it is -2... Please let me know what is unclear.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't provide any runtime functionality, so asking how to do a runtime thing "in TypeScript not Javascript" doesn't make any sense

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your nice explanation. I am OK to close this if this is really not possible...I wish people can explain and down vote just down voting..

Answer (score 4):

We can't. Browsers don't support this for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks. So far in my research also same thing. I was able to get client Ip address so was looking around for client machine name...

Comment: Evelijn.. We are doing splunk logging with userid and client ip address. Sometimes I get clientIP address but not username since authentication might fail. In such cases I wondering to log client machine name along with clientIp address since machine name will help locating the user...I hope this is clear.. please let me know...

Comment: @Ziggler Ah okay, I understand. Can I assume this is used for your IT back office? I'm not experienced in this field, so I don't think I can help you, sorry...